# Optional string array as binding argument SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

How can I have an optional argument of type `Binding<[String]>` in the init function?

```swift
@Binding var counter:Int
@Binding var strings:[String]


init(counter:Binding<Int>, strings:Binding<[String]>? ) {
    self._counter = counter
    self._strings = strings ?? Binding.constant([String]())
}


// creating a new view as follows throws an error
MyView(counter: $counter)
```

The error I get is:

> Missing argument for parameter 'strings' in call

Answer (score -1):

I found the following solution that works:

```swift
init(counter:Binding<Int>, strings:Binding<[String]> = Binding.constant([String]())) {
    self._counter = counter
    self._strings = strings
}
```